# How to extract tables from websites from a list of links in excel sheet?

Tags: html, excel, web-scraping, uipath

I am having trouble iterating through a list of links within an excel sheet.

[image]

How do I link the excel sheet to the for loop in Uipath?

I tried using Get Workbook Sheet to extract the table from the excel file.

[image: Sequence]

Here are the properties for Get Workbook Sheet.

[image]

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you should add more context around what else you have tried and why those approaches didn't /won't work to your question using [edit]. As it stands, saying "is there a better way" but in comments saying _I can't do it that way because_ _x_, is not helpful in eliciting answers that may have help you and answer that question/

Comment: While scraping if you are scraping link you can extract the text and the URL, https://imgur.com/PpjaJ6C

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use VBA or "macros" to do that. Basically, the process would be to reference the MSXML library (whatever the latest/greatest one is) and then use XML HTTP Request (XHR) to fetch the whole page. So, that would be inside a loop/iteration of all the URL's ("cells"). Then you will need to parse the XHR result as HTML then query for all `table` elements. Then a simple "paste" will usually work - so maybe use VBA to paste into a new sheet.

Comment: I was exploring that option but I cant retrieve anything due to the security restrictions present where I am. I am using UiPath only as a last option. Thank you for the insight.